# Java video automatic recoding does not working as expected

Tags: java, screen-recording

I'm using java *monte screen recorder* *jar* file in order to record my screen while executing java code,

this is my code:

```
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.EncodingKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.FrameRateKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.KeyFrameIntervalKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MIME_AVI;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MediaTypeKey;
import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MimeTypeKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.CompressorNameKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.DepthKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.QualityKey;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.monte.media.Format;
import org.monte.media.Registry;
import org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MediaType;
import org.monte.media.math.Rational;
import org.monte.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder;

public class MonteRecorder extends ScreenRecorder {

    private File movieFolder;
    private String name;

    public MonteRecorder(String name, File movieFolder) throws IOException, AWTException {

        super(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
                .getDefaultConfiguration(),

                 new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
                    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                            CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE, DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey,
                            Rational.valueOf(15), QualityKey, 1.0f, KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
                    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black", FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
                    null);
                /* output format for audio - null == no audio */
            this.movieFolder = movieFolder;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected File createMovieFile(Format fileFormat) throws IOException {
        if (!movieFolder.exists()) {
            movieFolder.mkdirs();
        } else if (!movieFolder.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IOException("\"" + movieFolder + "\" is not a directory.");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH.mm.ss");

        File f = new File(movieFolder, //
                "Scenario - " + name + " - " +dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "."
                        + Registry.getInstance().getExtension(fileFormat));
        return f;
    }



}
```

file type is .avi and it's created successfully. 
but when trying to open it using VLC media player, I'm getting the following error message:

**This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.
0xc00d36c4**

[image: error message]

note: this code worked successfully before some weeks, but I did not tested it constantly.

in order to fix it I tried to change format parameters, to MP4 or quicktime (.mov) file , it's all failed to be opened.

if someone know another maven library that can record the screen it will be helpful(with code example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem occurred because o does note invoked stop method at the end of screen recording.
before is started the screen recording by using the following code:

```
ScreenRecorder screenRecorder = new MonteRecorder(videoName, new File(path));
this.screenRecorder.start();
```

to fix the problem I should add

```
this.screenRecorder.stop();
```

at the end of the scenario.

after adding it, created video start as expected using VLC media player.